# Как найти точку пересечения кривой и прямой?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть кривая

```
y^2 = x^3 - 7x + 10
```

Есть две координаты на кривой `P[1,2]` и `Q[3,4]`

Как найти 3-ю координату? Подскажите алгоритм На графике это [-3,-2]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы ищете точку **пересечения** кривой и прямой.

Решив систему уравнений, составленную из формул кривой и прямой - вы найдете `X` компоненты всех точек пересечения данных прямой и кривой.

---

Для этого нужно сначала получить уравнение прямой по координатам двух точек, через которые проходит эта прямая:

```
x - x1      y - y1
-------  =  -------
x2 - x1     y2 - y1
```

подставив координаты точек `Q` и `P`, получим уравнение прямой: `y = x + 1`

теперь подставим его в уравнение кривой:

```
(x + 1)^2 = x^3 - 7x + 10
```

решив данное уравнение вы найдете `X` координаты всех точек пересечения прямой и кривой.

```
x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 1 - 7x + 10 = 0
```

=>

```
x^3 - x^2 - 9x + 9 = 0
```

=>

```
x^2 * (x - 1) - 9 * (x - 1) = 0
```

=>

```
(x - 1) * (x^2 - 9) = 0
```

=>

```
(x - 1) * (x - 3) * (x + 3) = 0
```

получаем три корня уравнения:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 3
x3 = -3
```

подставив новый корень в уравнение прямой `y = x + 1` - получим `y` координату третьей точки:

```
y3 = -3 + 1 = -2
```

---

```
R (-3, -2)
```